# Switching system is not working as intended, unless I use my meter prob whose Negative is on ba3 negative , how can I fix it?

Tags: switching

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8tlCX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want a circuit that could turn on a system and as well turn of that system, and sometimes work as an automatic switch pls guys take a look at the diagram. I'm using a CD4011 ic which have NAND Gate.
The problem now is that, it does work but not perfectly, because some times when I turn on preset `1` no voltage will come out except if I use my meter prob to torch the switch supply before it will now start to work the way I intended, pls guys help out what can resolve this?

Comment: how it it supposed to work?

Comment: There is no "ba3 negative" on your diagrams. Please explain why you have diodes.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the circuit is not applying 0V to inputs, it only applies 5V when button is pressed but it will float when button is released. Floating inputs are bad as they can float at any voltage between logic high or low or halfway which can consume excess current. The input stays charged to 5V until it slowly decays or connecting a multimeter will discharge it to 0V. This can be fixed by putting pull-down resistors to the inputs so they keep the voltage at 0V unless button is pressed.

Comment: Pls justme thanks a lot for the explanation and as well the solution to my question but please u made mention of adding a pull down resistor to the inpute, but I don't know which inputs I will add this, is it the inputs of the cD4011 ic or the inpute powering my preset

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw8b4U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yeah. it is, pls the pull done resistor there were is it attached to? Is it Tue other end of the inpute? Or to ground?

Comment: "logic ground"  in other words to the same place as pin 7 of the chip.